# How to display Flickr Images via API in a Justified Gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, flickr

I need to use the Miromannino Justified Gallery (http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) but I need it to display images retrieved from Flickr.

I got the code down for retreiving the photos from Flickr via API using Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/",
        data: {
            method: "flickr.photos.search",
            api_key: "671aab1520e2cb69e08dd36a5f40213b",
            tags: "beach,fashion",
            format: "json",
            nojsoncallback: 1
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response.photos.photo, function (index, value) {
                $("#mygallery").append("<div><img src='http://farm" + value.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + value.server + "/" + value.id + "_" + value.secret +".jpg'></div>");
            })
        }
    });
```

But I just do not understand how to add in the Justified Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

JustifiedGallery expects each image to be wrapped in an `<a>` tag. Lastly, you have to call `.justifiedGallery()` at the end. Here's the modified code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/",
    data: {
        method: "flickr.photos.search",
        api_key: "671aab1520e2cb69e08dd36a5f40213b",
        tags: "beach,fashion",
        format: "json",
        nojsoncallback: 1
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response.photos.photo, function (index, value) {
            console.log(value);
          var url = 'http://farm' + value.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + value.server + '/' + value.id + '_' + value.secret + '.jpg';
          var a = $('<a>').attr({href: url});
          var img = $('<img>').attr({src: url});
          a.append(img);
          $("#mygallery").append(a);
        });
        $('#mygallery').justifiedGallery();
    }
});
```

And here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/tghw/raf1m6bL/

Comment: shouldn't an api_key not be published and used in frontend?